# Excel VBA -- three consecutive cells have the same interior.colorindex, but the range of these three cells returns different colors

Tags: vba, excel, colors

I have three consecutive cells (A1,B1,C1) which all have interior.colorindex of 15. But if I check if cells(A1).resize(1,3).interior.colorindex = 15, it returns False... cannot figure out why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cell interiors can have the same `ColorIndex` but still have different `Color`. Maybe this is your problem?

`Range("A1").Resize(1, 3).Interior.ColorIndex` will only return 15 if all three cells have the same `ColorIndex` *and* `Color`. If `Color` differs, then it will return `Null`, even if `ColorIndex` is the same.

Excel workbooks have a predefined palette of 56 colors. Each of these is associated with a color index between 1 and 56 (0 means no color). (You *can* [edit a workbook's color palette](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/change-the-color-palette-in-a-workbook-HP005198935.aspx) to change what color each index refers to.)

If you assign to a cell interior a `Color` that is not part of the palette, and then ask what `ColorIndex` it corresponds to, then the index will snap to that of the closest color in the palette (smallest RGB distance, I think). This is why two somewhat different `Color`s can return the same `ColorIndex`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But their colors do look very similar. How should I solve this problem? I can use "if Range("A1").interior.colorindex=15 and Range("B1").interior.colorindex=15 and ... then" or a for loop instead of "if Range("A1").Resize(1, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 15". But I'm wondering if there is a more concise way.

Comment: If `ColorIndex` is important to you, then yes, a loop seems like the way to go. Maybe you can use [these functions](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Colors.aspx) to avoid writing things from scratch. But then, do you really want `ColorIndex´, or is `Color` really what you're looking for?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett I have given a workaround the get a boolean value based only on the ColorIndex property and not taking the Color into an account